# NoMethodError in UsersController#create -- did you mean super?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey creating a simple app here and having trouble with signing up users. I keep getting this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCQ28.png). I had it working before and suddenly now it doesn't know what user is. Any help would be greatly appreciated

here is my code for userscontroller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
 
  def show
    redirect_if_not_logged_in
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]) #if it doesnt find anything find_by_id will throw nil whereas just find will throw error
    redirect_to '/' if !@user
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end


end
```

Views...

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%>
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "sessions#home"

  #signup route
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/signup' => 'users#create'

  #login route
  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
```

Here is the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :categories, through: :recipes
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_recipes, through: :comments, source: :recipe 
  has_secure_password 

  validates :user, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
end
```

Comment: The code which I can see in your error image is different than what you have posted here. You are missing some details on the question probably. In the image for example, it is using local variable `user` and on the controller code it is using instance variable `@user`

Comment: Hey i uploaded the wrong screenshot, its changed now.

Comment: Could you paste your `User` model code too, I think the issue is there

Comment: Hey Deepesh, i just uploaded the user model

Comment: Change `validates :user, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true ` to `validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true` and try

Comment: Added an answer with more details. And here is what you could do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the validation you have added:

```
validates :user, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

It never needs model name `:user` just the attribute name:

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

You can read more about it here:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers